# Create a matrix of plots programatically in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, plot, distribution

I would like to create a 5x5 matrix of plots that loop over the `n` and `p` variable below. The 25 "small multiples" are arranged into one graphic. This can be done in `ggplot2`, but the non-ggplot solutions are also welcome.

Here is my start:

```
n <- 1000
p <- 0.01
bd1 <- rbinom(n, n, p)
bins <- seq(min(bd1), max(bd1), 1) # optional count bins

ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = bd1, y =..count..), breaks = bins)

count_vector <- c(10,50,100,500,1000)
prob_vector <- c(0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Update: I believe instead of `breaks`, we can simply use `binwidth = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do this with `gridExtra` and `ggplot2`. There exist multiple packages to do this though:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

make_plot <- function(count, prob) {
  bd1 <- rbinom(count, count, prob)
  bins <- seq(min(bd1), max(bd1), 1) # optional count bins
  
  ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = bd1, y =..count..), breaks = bins) + 
    ggtitle(sprintf("count = %s\nprob = %s", as.character(count), as.character(prob)))
}

count_vector <- c(10,50,100,500,1000)
prob_vector <- c(0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5)

nrows <- length(count_vector)
ncols <- length(prob_vector)

plots <- matrix(list(), nrows, ncols)
for (i in seq_along(count_vector)) for (j in seq_along(prob_vector)) {
   plots[[i, j]] <- make_plot(count_vector[i], prob_vector[j])
}

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs = plots))
```

the last statement gives me:

[image]

The top left figure failed but that has something to do with the input parameters.

Comment: Awesome! oops, yes $0.995^10 = 0.951$, so it's a really low chance of observing even one success.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `patchwork` approach and using a loop. I have made slight changes on your code to work with dataframes as this data adapts better to `patchwork` method `wrap_plots()`. Here the code:

```
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

#Vectors
count_vector <- c(10,50,100,500,1000)
prob_vector <- c(0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5)
#Data
df <- data.frame(count_vector,prob_vector=rep(prob_vector,each=5))
#Create a list
List <- list()
#Loop for plots
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1])
{
  set.seed(123)
  #Code
  bd1 <- data.frame(v1=rbinom(df$count_vector[i], df$count_vector[i], df$prob_vector[i]))
  bins <- seq(min(bd1$v1), max(bd1$v1), 1)
  #Plot
  L <- ggplot(bd1,aes(x=v1)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y =..count..), breaks = bins)+
  labs(title = paste0('N = ',df$count_vector[i],'\np = ',df$prob_vector[i]))
  #Assign to list
  List[[i]] <- L
}
#Final plot
wrap_plots(List,ncol = 5)
```

Output:

[image]